# Google API gives "unused Javascript" in Pagespeed

Tags: javascript, google-api, pagespeed

I am using the Google Places- and Geocoding-API to autocomplete addresses.
I include it like this in my `<head>`:

```
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places,geocoding"></script>
```

Pagespeed gives the warning to remove "[unused Javascript](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/performance/unused-javascript/)". However, I am really using the Google-API on that page.

[image: Google Pagespeed error]

How would I include these Google API's without getting the warning on Pagespeed?